# How do I get this function to return a value?

Tags: php, function, return-value

I've copy-pasted a function that I'm trying to modify. I'd like to make it handle errors properly. Right now, `$smtpResponse` doesn't return any values. When I echo values within the function, they DO show, but `$smtpResponse` doesn't yield anything, and neither does sending true or false values.

I tried returning "Fail" and "Success" too, but they're not showing. `$response` doesn't show, but "It worked!" does. Why isn't the function returning anything?

I'm trying to output as follows:

```
//Send e-mail  
$repsonse = authSendEmail($from, $namefrom, $sendto,"", $subject,$message);

//Report success/failure
echo $response;

The culprit: 

function authSendEmail($from, $namefrom, $to, $nameto, $subject, $message) {
    //Connect to the host on the specified port  
    $smtpConnect = fsockopen($smtpServer, $port, $errno, $errstr, 60);  
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  

    if(empty($smtpConnect)) {  
        $output = "Failed to connect: $smtpResponse";  
        echo $output;
        return "Fail";
         //return false; 
         //used to read 'return $output' 
    }  

    else {  
        $logArray['connection'] = "Connected: $smtpResponse";  
    }  

    //Request Auth Login  
    fputs($smtpConnect,"AUTH LOGIN" . $newLine);  
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  
    $logArray['authrequest'] = "$smtpResponse";  

    if(!$smtpResponse) {
        return "Fail";
    }

    //Send username  
    fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($username) . $newLine);  
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  
    $logArray['authusername'] = "$smtpResponse";  

    if(!$smtpResponse) {
        return "Fail";
    }

    //Send password  
    fputs($smtpConnect, base64_encode($password) . $newLine);  
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  
    $logArray['authpassword'] = "$smtpResponse";  

    if(!$smtpResponse) {
        return "Fail";
    }

    //Say Hello to SMTP  
    fputs($smtpConnect, "HELO $localhost" . $newLine);  
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  
    $logArray['heloresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";  

    if(!$smtpResponse) {
        return "Fail";
    }

    //Email From  
    fputs($smtpConnect, "MAIL FROM: $from" . $newLine);  
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  
    $logArray['mailfromresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";  

    if(!$smtpResponse) {
        return "Fail";
    }

    //Email To  
    fputs($smtpConnect, "RCPT TO: $to" . $newLine);  
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  
    $logArray['mailtoresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";  

    if(!$smtpResponse) {
        return "Fail";
    }

    //The Email  
    fputs($smtpConnect, "DATA" . $newLine);  
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  
    $logArray['data1response'] = "$smtpResponse";  

    if(!$smtpResponse) {
        return "Fail";
    }

    //Construct Headers  
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $newLine;  
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . $newLine;  
    $headers .= "To: ".$nameto." <".$to.">" . $newLine;  
    $headers .= "From: ".$namefrom." <".$from.">" . $newLine;  
    fputs($smtpConnect, "Subject: $subject\n$headers\n\n $message \n.\n");  
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  
    $logArray['data2response'] = "$smtpResponse";  

    if(!$smtpResponse) {
        return "Fail";
    }

    // Say Bye to SMTP  
    fputs($smtpConnect,"QUIT" . $newLine);   
    $smtpResponse = fgets($smtpConnect, 515);  
    $logArray['quitresponse'] = "$smtpResponse";   

    if(!$smtpResponse) {
        return "Fail";
    }

    echo "It worked!";
    return "Success"; 
    //insert var_dump here -- uncomment out the next line for debug info
    //var_dump($logArray);
}
```

Comment: I highly suggest that you ditch that code and use Zend_Mail, PHPMailer, SwiftMailer or something similar.  Anyway, if it's not returning anything, then that must mean that !$stmpResponse is never true.

Comment: Uncommenting var_dump($logArray) gives a lot of information, so it's unlikely that smtpResponse is never true. For each 'true' value, an additional line is added to $logArray. I decided to use this function so I could debug it if necessary. I did look at each of the other options you mentioned, but this is the easiest to integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:) you have a typo

```
//Send e-mail  
$repsonse = authSendEmail($from, $namefrom, $sendto,"", $subject,$message);

//Report success/failure
echo $response;
```

you return $**repsonse** and you echo $*response*

And for the record. Copy/pasting somebody elses code won't take you anywhere. If you want to learn to program write the code yourself or if you really need to copy / paste try to understand what you are copy/pasting. I'm not trying to be mean just giving you a word of advice. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Vlad! GOOD EYE! Indeed, I completely agree with you. If I hadn't been trying to understand the code, I wouldn't be trying to handle errors...and wouldn't have this problem! I'm still not getting a response though.

Comment: my advice to you is to start writing that function from scratch and debug it step by step. write the connect part and check the return value, write the login part and check the return value and so on. Also look into xdebug, that will help you see what code paths are called. From my experience, when the code mysteriously starts to break it's better to start from scratch. good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Vlad. I ended up using the php mail function instead. Even though it always returns false (documented problem with my version of php that isn't hard to solve), I've never had an actual failure in sending the mail. When I find out a bit more about how sockets work and how to catch related errors properly, I'll use the copypasted code as a standby method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too simplistic but, do you really have a line like:

```
//Report success/failure echo $response;
```

That echo is just part of a comment, you need to put it on a new line.

Also, you should really close that socket connection before exiting your function.

Also, it might be nicer to return boolean true on success and false on failure, IMHO.

Comment: These are not solving the problem!

Comment: So your echoes from within the function (such as, "It worked!") are being echoed properly but when you echo the return value of the function (which is a string in every case) you get nothing? This is very odd. Can you elaborate on your efforts to echo from within the function? Have you tried echoing something just before each of your returns so you determine when you are exiting the function?

Comment: I assume "The culprit:" is not actually in the code you are attempting to run. That would surely cause some problems.

Comment: "The culprit" IS the code I'm attempting to run. What problems would it cause, because those are probably the ones I'm facing.

Comment: If you just write "The culprit:" in your php code, your script will die with `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING`. Bear in mind, I'm not talking about your code. I'm talking about the the actual text "The culprit" which you have written here as if it is part of your code. I assume it actually is not because you would notice that probably very quickly.